# Possible security vulnerability from using fgets() and recommended solution?

Tags: c, fgets, buffer-overflow

I'm using coverity's SA tool for errors. I'm getting a few errors due to the usage of fgets(). This is a snippet (SA errors shown as comments)-

```
FILE *fp;
char my_pubkey[1024];

fp = fopen("publickey.pub", "r");

//tainted_string_argument: fgets taints variable my_pubkey.
if (!fgets(my_pubkey, sizeof(my_pubkey), fp)) {
    printf("failure to read pub key file");
    goto error;
}

//tainted_string: Passing tainted string my_pubkey to a parameter that cannot accept a tainted format string.
if (fprintf(fp, my_pubkey) != strlen(my_pubkey)) {
    printf ("failure to write pub key in key file");
    goto error; 
}
```

In my investigation, some reports suggest using getline() instead, but is that really needed? If this is a valid issue, what can be the vulnerability? And what's the best solution?

EDIT: If this is a false positive, why so? What can be an example of when it would be an actual issue?

Comment: `strlen` and `printf` in its current form might cause issues if working with "tainted" strings if these are not sanitized properly (if the null-termination is not where it is expected). But it is not your case. `fgets` is taking care of it.

Comment: Actually, no, sorry. It is *not* ok. What will happen if the sting is containing some format specifiers? So not, the tool is right. It's a true positive.

Comment: `fgets` add the newline char if encountered before reading `sizeof(my_pubkey)-1` chars. Can this be an issue for your application?

Comment: @Bob__ It adds the `\0` termination, not a newline. Which is a desired behavior.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That's not what reference says http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/ or http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets

Comment: @Bob__ Please cite the line saying it will append a newline.

Comment: @Bob__, `fgets()` does not *add* a newline.  It *includes* the newline that it reads from the file, if it indeed does read one, as opposed to automatically stripping it.

Comment: "A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str."

Comment: @Bob__ This line means that if `fgets` is encountering a newline character in the input string, it is copied into the buffer as any other character and terminating *after* reading it. Nothing about non-existent newlines.

Comment: Never talked about non-existent newline. Getline doesn't copy it, I was wondering if that could be an issue.

Comment: @Bob, perhaps better to say "`fgets` _includes_ the newline char if encountered before reading sizeof(my_pubkey)-1 chars.".  "Add" confuses. BTW: common `getline()` _does_ copy it:  "The buffer is null-terminated and includes the newline character, if one was found." http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html

Comment: @chux yes, language confusion and yes, wrong function example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coverity seems to be complaining that `my_pubkey` is receiving a value from an external source.  It is therefore "tainted", because the program cannot inherently be confident that the data so received are correct or valid.  This is a genuine concern that you may simply need to manage.  I wouldn't expect using `getline()` instead of `fgets()` to change that -- that would be one way to address a different problem involving a different function (`gets()`).

Coverity is *also* complaining that you are passing your tainted string to `printf()` *as a format string*.  This is also a *bona fide* security concern, and maybe even a simple correct functionality concern.  It is a very bad idea to use an externally supplied string as a `[f]printf()` format string, because such a string may contain `printf()` field codes.  You should instead either provide an explicit format:

```
fprintf(fp, "%s", my_pubkey)
```

or use `fputs()`:

```
fputs(my_pubkey, fp)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the key is text up to 1024 printable characters, then code should use `char my_pubkey[1024+ 2];` to make space for the `\n` and `\0`.

If the key is binary, then opening in text mode is wrong and using `fgets()` fails as that reads a *line*.  Better to use `fgetc()`.  Also not use `strlen()` as code is not dealing with *strings*.

Further, *internal* buffer length should be minimized to reduce copies of the key floating around in stale buffers.  See `setbuf()` and `setvbuf()`.

---

`fprintf()` interprets the string, as coded, as a format specifier string.[@Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351018/possible-security-vulnerability-from-using-fgets-and-recommended-solution/39351231#comment66032173_39351018).  The presence of `%` introduces potential UB.  Better to use `%s`.

```
if (fprintf(fp, "%s", my_pubkey) ...
```